# assets pipeline behind login

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, authorization, asset-pipeline

I have developed a rails app that currently uses a lot of javascript.

Most of this javascript is code that I have generated myself, and is generally only used in a few places (all by authenticated users).

Basically, what I would like to do, is to be able to only allow a user access these js files if they are logged in and authorized (I use devise and cancan for authentication and authorization).

I would still like the files to be precompiled (concatenated and minimised) the same as the asset pipeline does, but these files should then be stored somewhere not accessible to the public, and served by rails (or similar) only when the user is authorized to access them.

I have tried and failed searching, but feel I must be missing something simple as this is surly common practice in a lot of rails apps.

Therefore, I was hoping to get some help finding information on this matter as I'm at a loss of what I can do other than compiling the js file manually and adding this to a view the user is authorized to access.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

To Clarify what I'm asking:
I want to try to find something similar to the asset pipeline that will concatenated and minimize the js files as normal.

Then, when the user tries to access this js file:
1. If the user is logged in, the js file is served to the user as normal.
2. If the user is not logged in, the user is given a error message (or a 401 not authorized, or 404 not found, or similar), meaning a unauthorized user cannot access the script.

Basically, something similar as what happens when you try to access a json file you arn't entitled to view.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm looking at the same issue and haven't found a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply use different layouts for the logged-in users or render a partial, that includes your precompiled javascript.

e.g. in `application.html.haml`

```
- if current_user.
  = javascript_include_tag "your_special_user_js"
```

I don't know, if this answers your question, but it was my understanding, that you are trying to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. This will indeed only load the js if the user is logged in.     

But I was also hoping to make it so if any non-logged in user tries to access the js file '/assets/your_special_user_js.js' it will give them a 'accessed denied' message or something similar unless they were logged in.